# Botocore credentials cache

Tags: boto3, multi-factor-authentication, botocore, aws-sts

When i try to get the credentials saved in the cache for the mfa login to aws, i always get prompted the mfa code. But it's correctly saved in the cache when i login. Just never used.

```
cli_cache = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.aws/cli/cache')

params = {'profile': 'profile-name'}
provider = botocore.session.Session(**params)
provider.get_component('credential_provider').get_provider('assume-role').cache = credentials.JSONFileCache(cli_cache)

session = Session(botocore_session=provider)
```

Can someone help me with this mfa code being prompted every time?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's fixed, the code is correct. The issue was on the `duration_seconds` being different in `.aws/credentials` than what was set on the role on aws